# What is "syntactically parallel elements" in Java?

Tags: java, checkstyle

There is a rule "[4.5.2 Indent continuation lines at least +4 spaces](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.5.2-line-wrapping-indent)" in the Google Java Style Guide which says:

> > In general, two continuation lines use the same indentation level if and only if they begin with syntactically parallel elements.

Could someone explain what does "**syntactically parallel elements**" mean and provide some examples for this case?

Comment: The first token is contained by the same set of brackets and both are immediately after or not immediately after a separating token like comma or semicolon.

Comment: I guess it means two things that are the same level of nesting (or precedence) within the expression/statement.

Comment: In other words: `elements on the same syntacticall level`. Ex: all statements (and blocks) in a block are on the same level, level+1 of the sourounding block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Java Style guideline you are citing refers to the so-called *continuation indent*, which is the indent used after line-wrapping. The (potentially) *syntactically parallel elements* in this case are the expressions that you are wrapping.

Example 1 (syntactically parallel):

```
foo("bar"
    + "baz"
    + "boo");
```

Example 2 (*not* syntactically parallel):

```
foo("bar"
    + foo2("bar"
        + "baz"));
```

In example 2, the method call to `foo2()` is nested within the call to `foo()`, so the arguments of `foo2()` are not on the same level as the arguments of `foo()`, in other words: They are not "syntactically parallel".

In Google Java Style, this means that the `+ "baz"));` part *may* be indented more than 4 spaces.

That being said, I believe the term "syntactically parallel" is a creation of the author of that document; at least I haven't seen it used much anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it means that if the two elements are parsed out to the same construct, then they maintain the same indentation.  For example.

```
String[] elements = new String[] { "bob",
                                   "joe",
                                   "pete" };
```

makes some sense (even if it doesn't get formatted this way) because they are all `String` elements within the same array definition.

Also within a block

```
 {
    System.out.println("hi");
    actNow(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
      return 5;
    }
 }
```

`System.out.println("hi");`, `actNow(input);` and the for loop are indented equally because they are all statements within the same block.  Note that `return 5;` is not indented equally because it is a statement within the block of the for loop.  Thus `return 5;` is not syntactically equivalent to the other statements due to it's different block locality.